# `TypeMatcher` not working when used with `throwsA`

Tags: unit-testing, exception, flutter, dart

I have the following code in my app:

```
expect(() => dataSource.getLastPost(), throwsA(TypeMatcher<CacheException>()));
```

This results in the following error

```
Expected: throws <Instance of 'TypeMatcher<CacheException>'>
  Actual: <Closure: () => Future<PostModel>>
   Which: threw <Instance of 'CacheException'>
```

If I remove the TypeMatcher wrapping CacheException...

```
expect(() => dataSource.getLastPost(), throwsA(CacheException()));
```

then it still gives a similar error

```
Expected: throws <Instance of 'CacheException'>
  Actual: <Closure: () => Future<PostModel>>
   Which: threw <Instance of 'CacheException'>
```

I was wondering what I am doing wrong? Either way it's clear that we are expecting a CacheException and a CacheException is being thrown. Then why does the expect test not pass?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It *is* correct to write `throwsA(TypeMatcher<CacheException>())`

The problem is you're likely facing is, in the context of Flutter and tests, there are two classes with the name `TypeMatcher`:

- [TypeMatcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/TypeMatcher-class.html) from the package `matcher`, for tests
- [TypeMatcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TypeMatcher-class.html) from `flutter/widgets`, to navigate inside `BuildContext`.

They are both used the same way, aka `TypeMatcher<SomeClass>`. But only one of them is a `Matcher`, which tests understand.

Your problem being, you likely used `TypeMatcher` from `flutter/widgets`. And since it's not a matcher, then:

```dart
throwsA(TypeMatcher<MyClass>())
```

is interpreted as:

```dart
throwsA(equals(TypeMatcher<MyClass>())
```

---

The solution is to use the correct `TypeMatcher`, from `package:matcher/matcher.dart`.

But to begin with, you should **not** use `TypeMatcher` directly.

Instead of:

```dart
throwsA(TypeMatcher<MyClass>())
```

you should use the shorthand `isA<T>` matcher:

```dart
throwsA(isA<MyClass>())
```

This removes the name conflict entirely